# How to add 24 hours to a millisecondsSinceEpoch time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to add 24 hr on the selected date slot in the calendar in milliseconds since the epoch.
As in the below code if I add 24 hr it will give me 00:00 time for the same day so I tried to use this (23, minutes: 59, seconds: 59) which is wrong.
Please suggest...

```
    DateTime initialTime = selectedDate.value;
    DateTime finalTime = selectedDate.value.add(new Duration(hours: 23,minutes: 59,seconds: 59));
    
    int finalTimeInEpoch = finalTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    print('This is the initial time for selected day --> $initialTime and This is the final time for selected day --> $finalTime');
    int initialTimeForApi = initialTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    int  finalTimeForApi= finalTimeInEpoch;
    print('This is the initial time for selected day --> ${initialTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch} and This is the final time for selected day --> $finalTimeInEpoch in millisecondsSinceEpoch');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Like This

```
DateTime finalTime = selectedDate.value.add(Duration(hours: 24));
```

if this don fix the issue your problem is `selectedDate.value` is not a valid format date time